# Magento 2 custom module - get media base url

Tags: magento2, php, module, admin, extensions

I use this [module](https://github.com/magevision/blog/tree/master/ImageUploadConfigurationField) and I create a image upload field in my custom module. Everything is okay but I want to get the full url of image in the frontend. How I can do this?

if I use this in the Data.php

```
public function getImageUpload() {
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('module/general/image_upload', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
}
```

and this in phtml:

```
<?php echo  $config->getImageUpload(); ?>
```

is return only default/image.png in frontend and I need to ger the full path (include store url and media folder). And I don't add that acl.xml in my module because I don't understand very well what is mean. Can be this the problem?

Thank you
    UPDATE: Image.php file

```
namespace MageVision\Blog4\Model\Config\Backend;
class Image extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image
{
    /**
     * The tail part of directory path for uploading
     */
    const UPLOAD_DIR = 'blog/post4';
    /**
     * Upload max file size in kilobytes
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_maxFileSize = 2048;

   /**
     * Return path to directory for upload file
     *
     * @return string
     * @throw \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _getUploadDir()
    {
        return $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($this->_appendScopeInfo(self::UPLOAD_DIR));
    }
    /**
     * Makes a decision about whether to add info about the scope.
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _addWhetherScopeInfo()
    {
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Getter for allowed extensions of uploaded files.
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    protected function _getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'svg'];
    }
    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function getTmpFileName()
    {
        $tmpName = null;
        if (isset($_FILES['groups'])) {
            $tmpName = $_FILES['groups']['tmp_name'][$this->getGroupId()]['fields'][$this->getField()]['value'];
        } else {
            $tmpName = is_array($this->getValue()) ? $this->getValue()['tmp_name'] : null;
        }
        return $tmpName;
    }
    /**
     * Save uploaded file before saving config value
     *
     * Save changes and delete file if "delete" option passed
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function beforeSave()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        $deleteFlag = is_array($value) && !empty($value['delete']);
        $fileTmpName = $this->getTmpFileName();
        if ($this->getOldValue() && ($fileTmpName || $deleteFlag)) {
            $this->_mediaDirectory->delete(self::UPLOAD_DIR . '/' . $this->getOldValue());
        }
        return parent::beforeSave();
    }
```

the module url: https://github.com/magevision/blog/tree/master/ImageUploadConfigurationField

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you are uploading to the media folder then following could should just do fine:

```
<?php echo $block->getMediaUrl($config->getImageUpload());?>
```

Comment: thank you but it doesn't return anything, is blank, if you take a look in that module they have something a function called protected function _getUploadDir() in the Image.php

Comment: can you post your module files content? EDIT: didnt see your link

Comment: is done please take a look I edit my post

Comment: you have everything you need now? please let me know